# I don't have a domain name, just an ip

Tags: facebook-apps

Right now I don't have a domain name for the app I'm developing. I will but not soon.

When I try the debug tool I got the error "Object at URL is invalid because the domain 'ip_number' is not allowed for the specified application. You can verify your configured 'App Domain' at...

Of course I can't use my ip in the App domain field.

I've added the ip in the 'server ip whitelist'

What should I do to test my app?

Answer (score 1):

Some hosting providers allows you to get 3rd level domain for free. Your can try it or perhaps [this service](http://uni.me/) will be useful in your case.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me :(, but thanks for the answer.